# rails: accessing table from has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

```
["groups", "groups_users", "members", "questions", "users", "votes", "schema_migrations"]
```

As you can tell, I have a table named, "groups_users" yet I cannot seem to access it. I can access the "users" table by ***User***. I can access the "groups" table by ***Group***. But how exactly do I access "groups_users"? I have tried:

```
Groups_Users
Groups_User
GroupsUsers
GroupsUser
```

I have also tried the singular version of Groups. Any ideas on how to access it? Documentation would also help.

**Group**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a model for `groups_users` table if you want to access it

```
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "groups_users"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

You can also define your associations like this

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, :through => :group_users
end


class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users
end
```

You can read about the difference [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Answer (score 2):

Vimsha's answer is the right one; I'd also share my experiences with `HABTM` vs `HMT` for you:

> HABTM is only for if you have "non-accessible" data. Rails' join
>   engine treats HABTM as having no model, and consequently you can't access the data directly. HMT (`has_many :through`) works by having a model & then allowing you access to it

The difference between `HABTM` & `HMT` is basically the direct access through the model. HABTM is there for "quick and dirty" collection access; HMT is there for more substancial data access

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a model.

```
class GroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```